# How to get the duration of a youtube video using selenium [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

so, I want to get the duration of a youtube video using selenium and I am trying to use this:

```
duration = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']")[0]
pauseButton.click()
print('Video Length = '+duration.text)
```

But this mostly will just throw an error because the video duration isn't always showing. it'll show only if your mouse if hovering over the video player or if the video is paused.
Does anyone know how I can get the duration of any youtube video using python Selenium?

Comment: Have you tired the YouTube Api ?

Comment: when the video is on or Is it on the search screen ?

Comment: @AomineDaici  When the video is palying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code  it will find the duration and also get the duration in seconds.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, datetime

# create the driver and take in the profile preferences
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# navigate to the below youtube video
driver.get(url)

# Obtain the length of the youtube video
duration = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']")[0].text


# Obtain the length of the video in seconds
x = time.strptime(duration, '%M:%S')
x1 = datetime.timedelta(minutes=x.tm_min, seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()
print(x1)
```

Comment: if there is an advertisement before the video, this will return the duration of the Ad.